# Alfresco LDAP batch sync

Tags: ldap, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to connect my alfresco instance to our ldap server to authenticate users.

My configuration

```
# LDAP Authentication
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap
ldap.authentication.active=true
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://myurl:389
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=dc=example,dc=com
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=cn\=myCN,ou\=admin,dc\=example,dc\=com
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=secret
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=users,dc\=example,dc\=com
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=dc\=example,dc\=com
ldap.synchronization.attributeBatchSize=200
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=200
```

The problem is that I reach the sizelimit of the ldap server every time. I doesn't seem like the batch size is used. I cannot raise the size limit of the ldap server. Is there a way to process user data batchwise?

Alfresco throws the following error:

```
2021-04-01 13:28:54,863 ERROR [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization aborted due to error
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03010018 Error during LDAP Search. Reason:[LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded]
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry.processQuery(LDAPUserRegistry.java:1335)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry.access$14(LDAPUserRegistry.java:1287)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry$PersonCollection.<init>(LDAPUserRegistry.java:1524)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry.getPersons(LDAPUserRegistry.java:573)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.syncWithPlugin(ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.java:1775)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.synchronizeInternal(ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.java:739)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.access$16(ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.java:474)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer$7.doWork(ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.java:2138)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.onBootstrap(ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.java:2132)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.onApplicationEvent(ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer.java:2495)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory$ChildApplicationContext.publishEvent(ChildApplicationContextFactory.java:569)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:887)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory$ApplicationContextState.start(ChildApplicationContextFactory.java:824)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.start(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:1098)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:637)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:221)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:206)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:399)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:887)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:140)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException: [LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded]; remaining name 'ou=users,dc=example,dc=com'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3206)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2891)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:148)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:217)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:189)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry.processQuery(LDAPUserRegistry.java:1316)
        ... 49 more
```

Thanks for every help.

Comment: which version of Alfresco are you using? There was an issue [MNT-14001](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/blob/787d860c7b7c29e09e40ebb2f4c5ce0a2e70142e/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/security/sync/ldap/LDAPUserRegistry.java#L1609) not setting the CountLimit correctly.

Comment: I am using Alfresco Community - 6.0.7

Comment: OK - this seems not to be the issue. Did you check the max limits on your ldap server? e.g. on AD you can read from `CN=Default Query Policy, CN=Query-Policies, CN=Directory Service, CN=Windows NT, CN=Services, CN=Configuration, DC=YOUR_COMPANY, DC=YOUR_COMPANY_TLD`

Comment: According to our AD administrator (different unit) the size limit should be 1000. Thats why I tried 200 as a batch size. But even lower sizes won't work. I can set a filter so only a user with a specific id is returned. Then everything works. I hoped for the batch solution because I cannot change the size limit

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure "ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=1000" (or some other batch size) in alfresco-global.properties.  Are you sure you're editing the effective alfresco-global.properties?

Additionally, if you set "org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry" into debug, you should be able to see the bath size reflected in the log as:

```
Return result limit:
```

Comment: I am sure that I am using the effective alfresco-global.properties. Every other configuration in that file is used. I'll try the debug. Thanks for the hint.